# ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type ‘void*’ , in legacy code converted to c++

Tags: c, g++, void-pointers

i know its old problem , but what will be the easy solution to keep the old logic of c app (legacy) that now converted to c++ ?

in c its working :

```
void *p;
void *response = malloc(60 * 81);

p = response ;
p+=4;
```

in g++ gives : ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type ‘void*’
update:
if i change it to char* im getting this error:

```
char *p;
char *response = malloc(60 * 81);

error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’
```

also does char* can hold other types (basic ones ) like short , int , bool ? 
this is why it is used in this legacy code , to hold diffident types ,

Comment: The 4 there looks suspiciously like an approximation of `sizeof(void*)` which is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest would be to cast the `void *` to `char *`.  Since ISO C also forbids `void*` arithmetic, gcc treats it as a `char*` as an extension.  See this for more details: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

Answer (score 3):

It's only working in gcc. Pointer arthimetic on void * is undefined. Gcc treats it like a char * in that case. So the best way to fix your legacy code is to carefully change all those pointers to char *.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest might be to look for compiler options to change this behavior.

The best is probably to change the type to `char *`, since that seems to match usage and intent.

Answer (score 1):

Porting from gnu C to C++ is non trivial. Arithmetic on `void*` is not C, it is an extension.

Porting such things to C++ should be done more carefully, in particular if the C code was not too proper from the start. That data has an "intended" type, so you should use that type in C++ and not yet another second guess like `char`. Obviously this was not thought to be a C string, doing `+= 4` for C strings makes not much sense. So there is the assumption that the base type has a size of `4`, probably from the rest of the code you can guess how this has to be interpreted.

Once you have the proper type, use `new[]` to allocate the array. Don't use `malloc` in C++ if you can avoid it.

Answer (score -2):

Because of "arithmetic of pointeur" ...
if you write  `p += 4` it means : `p += ((sizeof(void *) * 4)`

Comment: This is incorrect. Gcc treats pointer arithmetic on void * as char *.

Comment: That would be `p+=(sizeof(void)*4)`, and of course that's not valid.  You need to know the intended type of `*p` to give the right answer